# How set up java application with personal LDAP SERVER, LDIF file

Tags: java, spring, ldap, ldif

I'm trying to use an embedded LDIF file to test my Java Application.

I put this parameter in the application.properties:

```
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif= C:\\Test.ldif
```

But if I try to test the application I still can be authenticated with the real credentials. It seems that is not loading the LDIF file.

How does Spring work with the ldif file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your browser you can find your file when you type the file URL:

eg:

```
file:///C:/Test.ldif
```

After that you can use this URL in your application.properties file:

```
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif = file:///C:/Test.ldif
```

Comment: In linux environment use this:
spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=file:///usr/local/test.ldif